# Why there is \$sin {( 4 \pi f_p)}\$ in FM's stereo equation instead of \$cos {(w_m + w_c )t}+cos{ (w_m-w_c) t}\$? It's a DSB-SC modulation?

Tags: modulation, frequency-modulation

equation here:
[Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FM_broadcasting#Stereo_FM)
DSB-SC here:
[DSB-SC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-sideband_suppressed-carrier_transmission)

Comment: Did you read the paragraph preceding the formula in Wikipedia? It's explained right there.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of the \$\sin\left(2\pi f_p t\right)\$ term is explained in the immediately preceding paragraph in the Wikipedia article:

> A 19 kHz±2 Hz[7] pilot tone, at exactly half the 38 kHz sub-carrier frequency and with a precise phase relationship to it, as defined by the formula below, is also generated. This is transmitted at 8–10% of overall modulation level and used by the receiver to identify a stereo transmission and to regenerate the 38 kHz sub-carrier with the correct phase.

This is not DSB-SC, because DSB-SC is an AM modulation format and the article you're asking about is about FM modulation.